# Adding a child application under Composite Installation in IIS

Tags: iis, c1-cms

We’re running into an issue where the URL rewrites we are using in the child application are not working. I suspect this is due to Composite overriding the rewrites.

Is there a guide to creating child applications under Composite, or a way to tell it to not use the default Composite Rewrite engine for child applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we went with was to move the application from being under Composite, to the Root level of the website and took care of any linking issues with rewrites. This will work until a better solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't Composite-specific, but if the rewrites are in the web.config
            It isn't Composite-specific, but if the rewrites are in the web.config (editable through the Composite interface) you should be able to wrap their parent node in a `<location>` tag:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        ...
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```